# Show that $P(B_1B_2\dots B_n)\geqslant \sum_{i = 1}^n P(B_i)-(n-1)$ using Boole's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

15) $\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i\right)^c = \bigcap_{i = 1}^n A_i^c$ to show that 
$$P(B_1B_2\dots B_n)\geqslant \sum_{i = 1}^n P(B_i)-(n-1)$$

Hint: Let $A_i = B_i^c$.

$\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i^c\right)^c = \bigcap_{i = 1}^n\left(B_i^c\right)^c$ - complementation law

$\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i^c\right)^c = \bigcap_{i=1}^nB_i$

I am kinda lost on how I am supposed to solve this because I have to use Boole's inequality.

Comment: You can quickly learn by reading our tutorial page [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Max thank you so much. I will try and rewrite the problem and get the picture removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boole's inequality is
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i\right)\leq \sum_{i = 1}^n P(A_i).$$

Actually, you don't need to make the substitution. But, since it's given, if $A_i = B_i^c$, then $A_i^c = B_i$ and $\bigcap_{i = 1}^n B_i = \bigcap_{i = 1}^n A_i^c$. Then consider
$$P\left(\bigcap_{i = 1}^n B_i\right) = 1- P\left(\left(\bigcap_{i = 1}^n B_i\right)^c\right).$$